# How to maintain aspect ratio on a header background image?

Tags: html, css, responsive

This is an issue that has plagued me ever since I've started really learning CSS. I know how to set a background-image and using background-size: cover to get it to scale. However, I don't know how to properly fit the image in the header of...let's say something like 10vh or 50%.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main-head {
  background: url('./header-image.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 70%;
}
```

I'll see...
[Example:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxfTl.png)

I've tried doing background-size: contain, and though it seems like to be more or less what I'm aiming for...I feel like the aspect ratio is...off...

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main-head {
  background: url('./header-image.jpeg');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 70%;
}
```

I had the body set to height: 100...and this was the result...
[Example:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8R9t.png)

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is have the background-image completely fit within the given container (Here it's main-head) but I don't know how this is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `background-position: center;` to keep the image center.
and if you want make `<img/>` auto scale. you can use `object-fit` to make it. (ps: IE not support `object-fit`)

Answer (score 0):

Update `background-size: cover` will maintain the aspect ratio.

Also, you may want to have the background centered by setting `background-position: center`;

```css
#main-head {
        background: url('./header-image.jpeg');
        background-size: cover; // <-- maintain the aspect ratio, make it cover the element
        background-position: center; // <-- this will make the background center
        height: 70%;
}
```